# Почему мы не можем изменить поле структуры объявленной в классе?

Tags: c#

Почему мы не можем изменить поле структуры объявленной в классе?

```
struct Struct
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}

class Class
{   
    public Struct Struct { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = new Class() {Struct = new Struct() {X = 10}};
        Console.WriteLine(str.Struct.X);
        str.Struct.X++;
        Console.WriteLine(str.Struct.X);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если коротко, потому что мутабельные структуры — зло. Если длинно, смотрите в ответ.

Answer (score 6):

Ответ. Потому что структуры - значимый тип, который копируется при обращении.
В классе:

```
class Class
{   
    public Struct Struct { get; set; }
}
```

При каждом обращении, свойство `Struct` всегда возвращает копию структуры.
При первом обращении вы получаете копию, в которой изменяете значение свойства `X`. Это изменение касается только копии, оригинал остается нетронутым.
При втором обращении, вы получаете еще одну копию оригинальной (не измененной) структуры.